# Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Date' is not valid on tryparse

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to do a `DateTime.TryParse` from a date-formatted string, to a new column that I created as part of a `DataView` table.  I am getting this error when the code runs `Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Date' is not valid.`

This is the line of code:

```
DateTime.TryParse(dr("IX_ArticleStartDate"), dr("nStartDate"))
```

And these are the values in my watch when it errors out.

```
+       dr("IX_ArticleStartDate")   "2015/3/11" {String}    Object
+       dr("nStartDate")    {}  Object
```

I was under the impression that a `TryParse` would return a `NULL` value if it fails to convert datatypes.  Is there something that I should be doing different to convert this string to a `DateTime` datatype?

dr is instantiated as a `DataRow`

`Dim dr As DataRow = dv0.Table.Rows(i)`

Comment: TryParse returns a Boolean indicating if the Parsing succeeded or not.  If not, the DateTime var passed has the same value as before.  Unless it is Nullable(Of DateTime) it wont be Nothing/null.  And DBNull is not the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB implicitly try's to cast the DBNull Value to DateTime, since the method signature of DateTime.TryParse is

```
Public Shared Function TryParse(s As String, ByRef result As Date) As Boolean
```

which fails. You can use a variable instead:

```
dim startDate as DateTime
If DateTime.TryParse(dr("IX_ArticleStartDate").ToString(), startDate) Then
    dr("startDate") = startDate
End If
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still gives the same error as in the original question.  IX_ArticleStartDate is string type but I've created nStartDate as a DateTime and am trying to convert the IX_ArticleStartDate into a DateTime and place it into nStartDate.

Comment: @user3267755 - I changed my initial answer. This should definitly work.

Comment: thanks, it worked!  Your explanation was great, thanks for including the signature for TryParse, it makes sense why the code was blowing up now.

Comment: @user3267755 - Just fyi: In such situation I usually use `dr("IX_ArticleStartDate").ToString()` because DBNull.ToString() returns and empty string which is fine in your case. If you don't to this, VB will try to cast dr("IX_ArticleStarteDate"), too. And that will fail for the same reason (cannot cast DBNull to String)

Answer (score 1):

A `DateTime` is a value type and cannot have a null value.  You can do something like this:

```
Dim result As DateTime

Dim myDate As DateTime? = If(Not dr.IsNull("IX_ArticleStartDate") AndAlso _
    DateTime.TryParse(dr.IsNull("IX_ArticleStartDate").ToString(), result), _
    result, New DateTime?)
```

In this example, the variable `myDate` is not actually a `DateTime`, it's a `Nullable(Of DateTime)` as indicated by the question mark `?` after `DateTime` in the declaration (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).  The `TryParse` method actually takes a `string` value as the first argument and an output parameter which is a `DateTime` value as the second argument.  If the parse is successful, it returns `True` and sets the output parameter to the parsed `DateTime` value; on the other hand, if the parse is *not* successful, it returns `False` and sets the output parameter to `DateTime.MinDate` which is not very useful because it's difficult to distinguish between a valid use of `DateTime.MinDate` and null.

The example makes use of a [ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) which either parses and returns the date value, if it's not null, or else returns a nullable date instead (`New DateTime?`).

You would then use `myDate.HasValue()` accordingly to determine if the value is null, and if it's *not* null, you can use its value: `myDate.Value`.

Comment: Interesting..I added your code, but it highlights the last question mark and says - 'The "?" character cannot be used here."

Comment: It's not a problem.  It now says that no 'TryParse' accepts this number of arguments..when I try adding the 2nd argument like in my question, it says 'Cannot infer a common type; Object assumed' ?

Comment: @roryap that won't work because DateTime.TryParse returns a boolean and expects two parameters (second parameter is a reference which will hold the result if return value is true).

Comment: @SchlaWiener -- You're right.  I've updated my answer.